# Using Dynamic URLs with more than one Variable in a Sitemap?

Tags: url, sitemap, dynamic

I have a site map with generated dynamic urls that I need included in the sitemap.  However, the sitemap seems to be generating an error on the `&` character, so that pages with more than one variable in the query string break the sitemap.  How can I fix this?  Here's an example:

```
http://example.com/index.php?action=view&id=10
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ampersand (&) character is a reserved character in XML (sitemaps are XML) and must be replaced with an XML entity that represents it. In this case that would be `&amp;` (all entities start with ampersand which is why it is reserved).

When the XML is parsed the `&amp;` entity in your url will be translated into plain `&`.

Comment: Note that if you're generating the URL through PHP, run the entire URL string through the htmlentities function to solve this problem. (http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)